# Rebase a branch with master with commits removed from master

Tags: git

Let's say you master looked like

`1 2 3 4 5`

Where 1 ~ 5 are separate revisions.
Now `branchX` looks like

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7`

Then, due to some reason some commits were removed from master,
So now

`1 2 4 5`

is how the master looks (`3` was removed).

I want to rebase `branchX` with `master`

It should look like

`1 2 4 5 6 7`

**Edit:**
Here in this simple example just `6 7`, just two commits were added, but in my real scenario, I have 200 commits added to `branchX`

Comment: How would you remove commits from `master`? I don't know of a way to do that.

Comment: master's history was re-written, and a commit was dropped

Comment: Track down the commit sha1 of 6 and 7. `git checkout branchX;git reset master --hard;git cherry-pick 6-sha1 7-sha1`.

Comment: @ElpieKay, check out the updates the question

Comment: maybe you can try rebase interactive? like git rebase -i. More here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Comment: @Jaydeep try `git cherry-pick 6-sha1..200-sha1`. And `git rebase --onto master-5-sha1 branchX-5-sha1 branchX-200-sha1` could work too but I'm not sure and I cannot verify it right now. If you use `git rebase --onto`, you may need reset branchX to 200-new-sha1 with `--hard` after the rebase is done. You can try Andrei's interactive rebase too.

Answer (score 2):

This is difficult, or sometimes even impossible, in general.  It's easier—in fact, sometimes *much* easier—if you add some constraints.

#### TL;DR: conclusions

If you have a suitable reflog entry, such as `master@{1}`, the command sequence is just:

```
$ git checkout branchX
$ git rebase --onto master master@{1}
```

If not, we must find an appropriate upstream limit commit:

```
$ limit=$(git rev-list --topo-order --cherry master...branchX | 
  sed -n -e 's/=//p' | head -1)
$ echo $limit    # if this is empty, there's no equivalent commit and you are SOL
$ git checkout branchX       # same as before
$ git rebase --onto master $limit
```

#### How we got here

First, remember that a branch name, in Git, names every commit reachable from the branch tip (the tip being the commit to which the branch name itself points).  Reachability here is determined by the arcs in the DAG, i.e., which commits are considered ancestors of which later commits.

Remember also that the true name of each commit is its SHA-1 ID, and these are all unique, and determined by the read-only contents of the commit object.  It's impossible to remove a commit: you can only *copy*  all its children, to *new* (different) commits, with the original children pointing back to the commit's parent(s) and their copied descendants pointing to the corresponding copied parent(s).

Your scenario says that you actually had this:

```
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master
             \
              F--G   <-- branchX
```

where each commit's parent is found by following the direct links in a generally-leftward direction.  The (single) parent of `G` is `F`; `F`'s parent is `E`; `E`'s parent is `D`, and so on, back to `A`, which has no parents at all (is a root commit).

The set of commits reachable from `master` is `A-B-C-D-E`.  The set of commits reachable from `branchX` is `A-B-C-D-E-F-G`.  The way you and Git can talk about "commits on branchX" without getting `A-B-C-D-E` is to use, not just `branchX`, but rather `master..branchX`.  This is the set of commits reachable from `branchX` *minus* the set reachable from `master`.

Then, to "delete" commit `C` from `master`, this must have happened:

```
     D'-E'  <-- master
    /
A--B--C--D--E   [master was this before the copies]
             \
              F--G   <-- branchX
```

Here `D'` and `E'` are actually *copies* of `D` and `E`.  The originals remain in the repository, and are still reachable from `branchX`.  ***The expression `master..branchX` no longer works,*** though, because `master` now names `E'` and ancestors, i.e., `A-B-D'-E'`.  This subtracts those commits—it's allowed to subtract away something that was not there in the first place, in set algebra—giving `C-D-E-F-G`, which is not what you want.

#### How to get what you want

The basic problem comes down to identifying commit `E`.  If we can find commit `E`, we can write `E..branchX`, i.e., the set of all commits reachable from `branchX`, minus the set reachable from commit `E`.  But how shall we find `E`?

If you are the one who re-pointed the name `master` to commit `E'`, this could be very easy.  All you have to do is save the SHA-1 hash of `E` somewhere first—and in fact, if you're the one who rewrote `master` this way, you *did* save it, in the reflog you have for your `master`.  The reflog entries are `master@{1}`, `master@{2}`, and so on.  You can view these with `git reflog master`.<sup>1</sup>  Each reflog entry also has a date-and-time stamp, so you can write `master@{yesterday}` or `master@{1.week.ago}` to look up the appropriate numbered entry based on a relative date.

That's the easiest way by far, and it works in all cases, even if `E` is the commit that was "removed".  Note that when we "remove" commit `C`, we must *copy* `D` and `E` to `D'` and `E'`.  That is because those two commits were *descendants* of `C` that were reachable from `master`.  Should we decide to remove `E`, though ... well, what are the children of `E` that are reachable from `master`?

That's right: *there are no such commits.*  We can simply point `master` back at commit `D`, leaving `A-B-C-D` on `master`, and `E` apparently unique to `branchX` now.  Any time *we* adjust *our* master like this, though, we make a reflog entry to keep the *previous* value, so once again, we can simply look in the reflog to discover that `E` is the interesting commit.

The problem here comes in if (a) we didn't adjust `master` ourselves or (b) we did do it, but so long ago that our reflog entries have *expired*.  (This occurs after 30 days by default for cases like commit `E`.)  In this case, we can only find `E` *if* there is some copy `E'` in the new chain.  Even then, we can still only find it if the copy `E'` has the same [*patch ID*](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-patch-id.html) as `E`.

Patch IDs are how `git cherry`, and hence `git rev-list`'s `--cherry-pick` and `--cherry-mark` options, work.  We make (or Git makes) the assumption that when a commit is copied, usually it's copied with no significant changes, such that a hash ID computed by examining a slightly stripped-down `git show` of the commit will come up with the *same* hash ID for the original and for the copy.  These patches are called *patch equivalent* and mark the paired-up commits as, in some sense, "equal".

We also must<sup>2</sup> make use of the symmetric difference notation, `master...branchX` or `branchX...master`.  Because it's symmetric, it doesn't really matter which order we use (except for the whole left vs right part in `--left-right` in `git rev-list`, which we will generally want).  What it does, in any case, is to produce the following set algebra operation:

```
A..B = (reachable(A) | reachable(B)) - (reachable(A) & reachable(B))
```

That is, produce the set of commits reachable from *either* branch tip, excluding those commits that are reachable from *both* branch tips.  Hence, given:

```
     D'-E'  <-- master
    /
A--B--C--D--E--F--G   <-- branchX
```

the symmetric difference gives us `D', E', C, D, E, F, G`.

Hence, if we run `git rev-list master...branchX`, we will get this complete set of commits.  All we have to do now is see that `D'` = `D` and `E'` = `E`, and somehow choose `E` from this set.  So now we add `--cherry-mark` to the `git rev-list` command: this marks `D'` and `E'` and `D` and `E` with `=` characters, and marks `C`, `F`, and `G` with `+` characters.  Here I have run it on a repo that isn't quite as detailed: in effect I just have `E` and `E'` plus one unique commit.

```
$ git rev-list --cherry-mark master...two
=dcbcb2774954437ef0906c6770c7deb924d9286e
+0af7c6a3cf5e49928de132c341c848be80ab84c7
=643b37ef242fdc35dfdd4551b42393af3eb91a85
```

OK so far, but there's an obvious problem: this lists both `E` and `E'`, and we only wanted `E`.  Well, let's back up a moment and do this other rev-list variant:

```
$ git rev-list --left-right master...two
>dcbcb2774954437ef0906c6770c7deb924d9286e
<0af7c6a3cf5e49928de132c341c848be80ab84c7
<643b37ef242fdc35dfdd4551b42393af3eb91a85
```

This marks each commit, not with `+` or `=`, but rather with `<` (left) or `>` (right).  The commit that's on branch `two`, that is "the same as" the one on `master`, is in fact `dcbcb27...`.  The commit that's on `master` that is the same as the one on `two` is `643b37e...`.  This left/right distinction gives us a way to identify which commit is `E` and which one is `E'`: the one we care about, for the sake of discarding, is the one on `branchX`, so whichever side of the symmetric difference we put `branchX` on, that's the side to take.

Now we can make use of one more `rev-list` option: `--left-only` or `--right-only`.  These may be used in combination with `--cherry-mark`, hence:

```
$ git rev-list --left-only --cherry-mark master...two
+0af7c6a3cf5e49928de132c341c848be80ab84c7
=643b37ef242fdc35dfdd4551b42393af3eb91a85
```

or:

```
$ git rev-list --right-only --cherry-mark master...two
=dcbcb2774954437ef0906c6770c7deb924d9286e
```

Thus, we can run this command and pick out just the `=`-marked commit(s) to find `D` and `E`.

In fact, there's a shorthand for `--right-only --cherry-mark` (though it also adds `--no-merges`), spelled `--cherry`.  We can put the branch we want (`branchX`) on the right and use this:

```
$ git rev-list --cherry master...branchX
```

Again, this spits out both `+` and `=` commits.  We want to find the `=` ones, so we run this through `sed`, telling it to remove `=` and print lines, or not print lines if there is no `=` to remove:

```
$ git rev-list --cherry master...branchX | sed -n -e 's/=//p'
```

and this will list the IDs of commits `D` and `E`.

We only really want `E` (and we can use `head -1` to get it, provided we make sure we get the commits in topological-sort order), but in fact, it doesn't entirely hurt to exclude `D` as well.  But if we're going to use `git rebase` to copy the `branchX` commits, we really do want to find just `E`, so our final command is:

```
$ limit=$(git rev-list --topo-order --cherry master...branchX | 
  sed -n -e 's/=//p' | head -1)
```

Now we can run our final `git rebase` command:

```
$ git checkout branchX    # if needed
$ git rebase --onto master $limit
```

This rebases, i.e., copies, commits that are on the current branch, i.e., `branchX`, excluding the limiting commit and anything earlier—hence excluding `E` and earlier—with the copies going after (`--onto`) `master`.

Note, though, that it's possible that there are no patch-equivalent commits in the symmetric difference.  In this case, if you are quite certain there was a removed commit, you will have to find the limiting (`E` in our example) commit yourself, through some other non-automated method.  Once you find the "commit `E`", the rest goes just as before, using the hash ID as the limit for the `--onto master` rebase.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that `git reflog branch` actually just runs `git log -g --oneline branch`.  This means you can run the same `git log` command but omit `--oneline`, or replace it with a `--pretty=format:...` or `--format=...` directive to make up your own format, vs the standard `--oneline` format.

<sup>2</sup>OK, "should". :-)  It is technically possible to do this manually, running `git patch-id` on each commit yourself.  But given that `git rev-list` does it *for* you, automatically, why bother?<sup>3</sup>

<sup>3</sup>Stubbornness and/or obstinacy.